# как преобразовать родительский массив объектов по количеству объектов в массиве в значении intervals?

Tags: javascript

```
как разделить родительский массив объектов в одном из его значений которого имеется вложенный  массив объектов?
в данном случае intervals



let schedule = [
    {
        "uuid": "1622cbad-ae24-4b5a-aa3d-9e6541386329",
        "name": "Проект 1",
        "intervals": [
            {
                "requisition": "0872ed53-74c1-4745-9be7-47885b3f8729",
                "num_nodes": 3,
                "start_day": 13,
                "end_day": 15
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "uuid": "99ee2597-3afe-47b1-932b-735a435bea78",
        "name": "Проект 2",
        "intervals": [
            {
                "requisition": "5a777410-821b-4ff4-bc06-a3fcb9b38eeb",
                "num_nodes": 1,
                "start_day": 22,
                "end_day": 23
            },
            {
                "requisition": "94a55c26-37c1-4f05-a69c-a60cf3dd45e4",
                "num_nodes": 1,
                "start_day": 15,
                "end_day": 16
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "uuid": "31c4510e-0733-4535-855e-391b3641c945",
        "name": "Проект 3",
        "intervals": [
            {
                "requisition": "86ebfa97-a744-41b2-a2cd-38c614f37c30",
                "num_nodes": 2,
                "start_day": 13,
                "end_day": 14
            }
        ]
    }
]


и на выходе получить массив такого вида
то есть разбить по количеству интервалов и вернуть в качестве его значение обьект со значениями 




let newSchedule = [
    {
        "uuid": "1622cbad-ae24-4b5a-aa3d-9e6541386329",
        "name": "Проект 1",
        "intervals": 
            {
                "requisition": "0872ed53-74c1-4745-9be7-47885b3f8729",
                "num_nodes": 3,
                "start_day": 13,
                "end_day": 15
            }
    },

    {
        "uuid": "99ee2597-3afe-47b1-932b-735a435bea78",
        "name": "Проект 2",
        "intervals": 
            {
                "requisition": "5a777410-821b-4ff4-bc06-a3fcb9b38eeb",
                "num_nodes": 1,
                "start_day": 22,
                "end_day": 23
            }
    },

    {
        "uuid": "99ee2597-3afe-47b1-932b-735a435bea78",
        "name": "Проект 2",
        "intervals": 
            {
                "requisition": "94a55c26-37c1-4f05-a69c-a60cf3dd45e4",
                "num_nodes": 1,
                "start_day": 15,
                "end_day": 16
            }
    },

    {
        "uuid": "31c4510e-0733-4535-855e-391b3641c945",
        "name": "Проект 3",
        "intervals": 
            {
                "requisition": "86ebfa97-a744-41b2-a2cd-38c614f37c30",
                "num_nodes": 2,
                "start_day": 13,
                "end_day": 14
            }
        
    }
]
```

Comment: Самый простой и очевидный способ - с помощью вложенных циклов. Что пробовали, что не получилось?

Comment: пробовал методы map и flatMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const schedule = [
  {
    uuid: '1622cbad-ae24-4b5a-aa3d-9e6541386329',
    name: 'Проект 1',
    intervals: [
      {
        requisition: '0872ed53-74c1-4745-9be7-47885b3f8729',
        num_nodes: 3,
        start_day: 13,
        end_day: 15,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    uuid: '99ee2597-3afe-47b1-932b-735a435bea78',
    name: 'Проект 2',
    intervals: [
      {
        requisition: '5a777410-821b-4ff4-bc06-a3fcb9b38eeb',
        num_nodes: 1,
        start_day: 22,
        end_day: 23,
      },
      {
        requisition: '94a55c26-37c1-4f05-a69c-a60cf3dd45e4',
        num_nodes: 1,
        start_day: 15,
        end_day: 16,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    uuid: '31c4510e-0733-4535-855e-391b3641c945',
    name: 'Проект 3',
    intervals: [
      {
        requisition: '86ebfa97-a744-41b2-a2cd-38c614f37c30',
        num_nodes: 2,
        start_day: 13,
        end_day: 14,
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(flatSchedules(schedule));

function flatSchedules(schedules) {
  return schedules.reduce((acc, schedule) => {
    if (schedule.intervals && schedule.intervals .length > 0) {
      schedule.intervals.forEach((interval) => {
        acc.push({ ...schedule, intervals: interval });
      })
    } else {
      acc.push({ ...schedule });
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```